# Put value to the top of stack

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, stack

I have a program that should take a value and put (push) it at the top box.

StackOfBoxes.cpp

```
StackOfBoxes::StackOfBoxes()
{
    m_top=nullptr;
    m_size=0;
}

bool StackOfBoxes::isEmpty() const
{
    if (m_size==0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int StackOfBoxes::size() const
{
    return m_size;
}

void StackOfBoxes::push(int value)
{
    Box* Box1 = new Box;
    Box1 -> m_previous = m_top;
    m_top=Box1;
    ++m_size;
}
```

StackOfBoxes.h

```
class StackOfBoxes
{
private:
    Box* m_top;
    int m_size;

public:
    StackOfBoxes();
    bool isEmpty() const;
    int size() const;
    void push(int value);
    int pop();
};
```

Box.h

```
class Box
{
    public:
        Box ();
        int m_value;
        Box* m_previous;
};
```

Box.cpp

```
Box::Box()
{
    m_value=0;
    m_previous=nullptr;
}
```

This is what the push class should do:

```
>void push(int value)
>
>>Puts the value in a box
>
>>Puts that box on the top of the stack
>
>>Increase m_size by 1
```

However I don't think this is working because I have memory leaks.

> Leak_DefinitelyLost|====|160 (16 direct, 144 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2|

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you ever clear the stack (deleting everything inside)?

Comment: @rubito how is m_top initialized?

Comment: It looks okay (except for not using `value`) by itself. You probably do not `delete` this box properly after use. We need complete code to be able to help better.

Comment: @Nik 
in the `StackOfBoxes .h` `private Box* m_top;'

Comment: @zch I have like 5 different files? Should I add them all?

Comment: You should add the files related to the StackOfBoxes class

Comment: I think your suppose to use value to initialize Box. `Box* Box1 = new Box(value);` But that's not your memory leak

Comment: I've added the extra files. There is also a pop() class but I haven't implemented it.

Comment: @rubito as mentioned by in other comments you are not deleting the box. Your sample code does not show how you are handling delete of memory assigned by new. Basically when run this program against memory check tool it would suggest that there is memory since it would not find a 'delete' for a 'new' being called in push func.

Comment: @Nik so after `m_top=Box1;` I should add `delete Box1;`?

Comment: @rubito no that way your linklist would have no data, what I meant was that since you are allocating data on heap the valgrind for example would complain that there is memory leak. Which on its part is correct as it could not find a delete for a new. As your list increases in size you would allocate more data on heap, which in eyes of valgrind is memory leak.

Comment: @rubito your program will continue to consume memory as long as you add new nodes with 'new' or 'malloc'. You could not shift to stack memory since Nodes have to persist in memory, hence choice of HEAP.

Comment: @rubito Your program is doing what it should do. What you can keep in mind is when you erase some nodes, then you should delete/free that memory.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but if I'm reading this correctly you're saying that I should have another function in charge of popping the top box?

Comment: @rubito My mistake for calling your STACK as linklist, but views remain same.  Ideally there should be a pop() function which would delete/free the memory.